# Show hyperlinks in javascript alert

Tags: javascript, url, href, alert, plaintext

Is it possible to show hyperlinks in javascript alerts? 
I mean, if I do something like

```
alert("<a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>LINK</a>");
```

the alert will show only the plain text "LINK".

Is it possibile to show it like a clickable url?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link in Javascript alert](/q/1733410/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. Use "custom" alert dialog, you have plenty jQuery plugins for this.

Answer (score 4):

It ***is*** possible if you make your own web browser, which you won't do, because… well, just because. Otherwise, it's impossible (still).

However, `alert` has always sucked, so a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) may be better.